# WiFi connection is closed on Client side but Server is still receiving

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code, where the server keeps listening to a client and returning a msg when it can receive the address of the client but when the WiFi of the client is disconnected the server breaks the while loop, here is the code I wrote

Client

```
import socket

def Main():

    host='192.168.100.144' #client ip
    port = 4005
    
    server = ('192.168.100.113', 4000)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    
    message = "cell"
    while message !='q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

Server

```
import socket

def Main():
   
    host = '192.168.100.113' #Server ip
    port = 4000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if data !='cell':
         break
        if data =='cell'
          print("From connected user: " + data)
    c.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

The problem is when I switch the WiFi of the client side the server still printing the message

```
 print("From connected user: " + data)
```

I'm expecting the Server to break when the WiFi is turned of, the other problem I'm getting from the client side is no buffer space is available

I tried also this second attempt

Server

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5050))

print("Server Starting")
sock.listen()

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("New connection " + str(addr))
```

Client

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('Server IP address', 5050))
```

Now what I want is to add to the code to find out if nothing is connected to the server. What is the code in this case?

Comment: Move the `print(...` below the `break`

Comment: I tried that but I still have the same problem

Comment: You can set a timeout on the socket ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout ) so that the server doesn't wait forever for a data packet.